# Getting a list of files with ftp_nlist() function in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, centos

I'm trying to develop a function that retrieves a list of files from a specific directory. However, the result is always null. What checks could I perform?  The directory permissions are correct.

I have tried disabling the firewall. I am running the code on a CentOs server.

```
function getFiles($Directory){

    $ftp_server = "123.123.123.123";
    $ftp_user = "User";
    $ftp_pass = "Password";
    $ftp_dir = "../magazines/"; //I have tried absolute path also

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
        die("Conexion error");
    }

    //ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);  //I have tried this so
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);   //I have tried false also

    $directory = $ftp_dir . $Directory;
    $files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $directory);

    if ($files) {
        //Do something...
    } else {
        ftp_close($conn_id);
        return "Files not found.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to list the directory with an interactive `ftp` program?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  The value of `$ftp_dir` was incorrect.